# C++ runtime polymorphism with templates

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

My program has observables and observers. Here is the observable.

```
template <typename E>
class Observable {
  private:
    std::list<E> observers;

  public:
    void addObserver(E observer) {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    void notifyAll() {
        for (auto & observer: observers) {
            observer.doSomething();
        }
    }
};
```

There is a base `AnimalObserver` and derived observers, `CatObserver` and `DogObserver`. `AnimalObserver` has a virtual method, `void doSomething()`. `CatObserver` and `DogObserver` implement this method.

```
class DogObserver : public AnimalObserver {

  public:
    DogObserver() = default;
    void doSomething() const {
        std::cout << "woof!";
    }
};
```

```
class CatObserver : public AnimalObserver {

  public:
    CatObserver() = default;
    void doSomething() const {
        std::cout << "meow!";
    }
};
```

I create my Observable and run my program like this:

```
auto observable = Observable<AnimalObserver>();
auto cat = CatObserver();
auto dog = DogObserver();

observable.register(cat);
observable.register(dog);

observable.notifyAll();
```

What happens is that `AnimalObserver`'s doSomething method is called two times, instead of `CatObserver` and `DogObserver` doSomething methods being called. I want to call the doSomething method of the derived classes, not the parent classes.

What I am trying to do is keep a list of different observers who are derived from `AnimalObserver` and call their `doSomething` behavior instead of the virtual function.

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I'm not even sure what to search for. I am reading about templates but am lost.

Comment: The problem you've encountered is extremely well known, and solved, and is called "object slicing".

Comment: I'm not that religious of a person, but God bless your soul @user2407038

Comment: Virtual functions in the parent class should be declared `virtual` in derived classes as well.

Comment: @Giogre - No, they should not. That runs the age old risk of accidentally overloading instead of overriding, and wasting hours in debugging time. They should be marked `override` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue is this: You must store a pointer to the base class AnimalObserver in your Observable class. You can do this in a number of ways. unique_ptr<> comes to mind.

Here's an implementation with some hints along the way. godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/1Gq35G

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct AnimalObserver
{
    virtual ~AnimalObserver() { }
    // Hint 1: Declare abstract so that it won't even compile if you use the 
    //  base class directly in a collection - i.e. and not a pointer to the base.
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
};

template <typename E>
class Observable {
  private:
    typedef unique_ptr< E > _TyPtrContained;
    std::list<_TyPtrContained> observers;

  public:
    void addObserver( unique_ptr< E > && rrobserver ) {
        // Remember that inside a method that receives a rvalue-reference, 
        //  it is an lvalue-reference and must be std::move()'d when passing to a 
        //  method that accepts an rvalue-reference.
        observers.push_back( std::move( rrobserver ) );
    }

    void notifyAll() {
        for (auto & observer: observers) {
            observer->doSomething();
        }
    }
};

class DogObserver : public AnimalObserver {
  public:
    DogObserver() = default;
    // Hint 2: Use override to ensure that you are overriding an actual 
    //  virtual and not just declaring a method with a different signature 
    //  than the base.
    void doSomething() const override {
        std::cout << "woof!";
    }
};

class CatObserver : public AnimalObserver {
  public:
    CatObserver() = default;
    void doSomething() const override {
        std::cout << "meow!";
    }
};

int
main()
{
    auto observable = Observable<AnimalObserver>();
    // Hint 3: You can assign a unique_ptr<derived> to a unique_ptr<base>.
    unique_ptr< AnimalObserver > cat = make_unique< CatObserver >();
    unique_ptr< AnimalObserver > dog = make_unique< DogObserver >();

    // We move the local unique_ptrs into the addObserver method so that
    //  they are then moved into the list using the rvalue-reference version
    //  of list<>::push_back().
    observable.addObserver( std::move( cat ) );
    observable.addObserver( std::move( dog ) );

    observable.notifyAll();
    // And, voila, things work...
}
```